# Optimising applescript to decrease energy impact

Tags: optimization, widget, base64, applescript, battery

I have this script that I created for a battery indicator widget that will show on my (Macbook pro) touch bar and have it set to re-run every 3 secs (to update the text and logo), but it is eating a lot of energy just running in the background and I was wondering if maybe there was a way to make it more efficient in some way in order to decrease battery consumption.

Here is the script:

(Keep in mind that the images for the icon are in base64 because I plan on sharing this widget with people who might know nothing about computers and therefor I can't have them download and save an image in a specific directory etc..)

```
set bat_empty_icon to "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAAEACAYAAABccqhmAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAACXBIWXMAAA3XAAAN1wFCKJt4AAABWWlUWHRYTUw6Y29tLmFkb2JlLnhtcAAAAAAAPHg6eG1wbWV0YSB4bWxuczp4PSJhZG9iZTpuczptZXRhLyIgeDp4bXB0az0iWE1QIENvcmUgNS40LjAiPgogICA8cmRmOlJERiB4bWxuczpyZGY9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkvMDIvMjItcmRmLXN5bnRheC1ucyMiPgogICAgICA8cmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIHJkZjphYm91dD0iIgogICAgICAgICAgICB4bWxuczp0aWZmPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3RpZmYvMS4wLyI+CiAgICAgICAgIDx0aWZmOk9yaWVudGF0aW9uPjE8L3RpZmY6T3JpZW50YXRpb24+CiAgICAgIDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPgogICA8L3JkZjpSREY+CjwveDp4bXBtZXRhPgpMwidZAAALzUlEQVR4Ae3dv69lVRUH8IdMDAxQTYjAWFAQEwsrAWNCYkFoJsgQO7UxYvQPoFWgMDYWxEYrbfzVAoUNgcRkEg2MFcWEhIIYYGhomOFXjOD6jjnkcmfemzez7ptz9r2fnay59915+9y1P/vsNeec+2P29jQCBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQINAXuKm/iUtbuLX+fLjioYqTFfes3N5R9zUCowpcqMTfqXh75fZM3X+p4qOKoVunAJyokZ+ueKzikYrjFRqBXRH4sAb6YsULFc9XvFexE+22GuVTFamMnwkG9oFLayFrImtja9vNNbKfVpyvsPAZ2Acu3weyNrJGslaGaIc9Bcg5/XMVDwwxKkkSmFfg1Xr6xyty7WDR7TAF4MEaQRb/3YseieQILEsgRwMpAq8sK60vZvOlL/542U8/rEf+XmHxX0bjAQIHCmTNZO1kDS22HXSuksT/VHFssdlLjMCyBbJ2vlfxRsVrS0x1v1OAHPanet2yxKTlRGAwgY8r3+9ULO504EoFIBf8zlY47C8EjcCGBHJN4P6KRV0YXL8GkFMCF/w2NOM2Q2BFIP+gZm0ddNq98us35u56AXiintZLfTfG3rPsnkDWVtbYYtrqKUDexZSLFXctJjuJENg+gXdrSPdVfLCEoa0eATxZCVn8S5gVOWyzQNZY1toi2nQEcKKyebPi9kVkJQkC2y1wsYZ3b8XsHyCajgDyqT6LvxA0AjdAIGsta24xLVcnN/XhjtdrW89UPFrhpcRC0IYWyD6cffnpiuzbm1onWXOLaPkyj1yQ6A7s09rGsxXZnkZgGwWyb2cfz77eXS9Zc4tYK6lu3cEE5FSFRmAXBLKvb6IIZO3N2nINIF/j1W2/qQ38rbsR/QkMIpB9Pft8t21i7XVz2PtjbaFzBJDzokUcyrQlbIDA4QWyz3evCWTtzdpyBJD3/nfaX6rz8F+O2AHQdycFss//tTny7tprPv3eXgrAyeZW/tXsrzuBUQXONhPvrr3m0/+/+/t10zkFyMskGoFdFMi+31k7WXuztrwTMAPotOndhJ1t6EtgVIHu+umOO+8qzEeNE+cq8hXlL1d8UnGo1qlgcw/+UAP0SwSOUKC7fo6if44sflvxlcOMu5vAYZ7D7xDYVoHu+jnK/hcK/RcVXz4Iv5vAQdv2dwS2XaC7fm5E/zM1CfseDXQT2PYJNj4CBwl018+N6v/vGsQ31gfiIuC6iJ8JXJtAFvAo7a1KNN9KlC8ludTyPgCNAIHdEPhqDTOfQvz8274VgN2YeKMkMAl8q+78fPrBKcAk4ZbA9QmMdAowjfDDupPvJTzvCGAicUtgdwSO11CfynAdAezOpBvp0QiMeAQQibxH4E4F4Gh2ClvdHYFRC0Bm6JRTgN3ZUY2UwLrAaQVgncTPBHZH4OsKwO5MtpESWBe42zWAdRI/E7g2gZGvAVxUAK5tsv02gXWBbgHIGuy01vM7BejQ60tgcAEFYPAJlD6BjoAC0NHTl8DgAgrA4BMofQIdAQWgo6cvgcEFFIDBJ1D6BDoCCkBHT18CgwsoAINPoPQJdAQUgI6evgQGF1AABp9A6RPoCCgAHT19CQwuoAAMPoHSJ9ARUAA6evoSGFxAARh8AqVPoCOgAHT09CUwuIACMPgESp9AR0AB6OjpS2BwAQVg8AmUPoGOgALQ0dOXwOACCsDgEyh9Ah0BBaCjpy+BwQUUgMEnUPoEOgIKQEdPXwKDCygAg0+g9Al0BBSAjp6+BAYXUAAGn0DpE+gIKAAdPX0JDC6gAAw+gdIn0BFQADp6+hIYXEABGHwCpU+gI6AAdPT0JTC4gAIw+ARKn0BHQAHo6OlLYHABBWDwCZQ+gY6AAtDR05fA4AIKwOATKH0CHQEFoKOnL4HBBRSAwSdQ+gQ6AgpAR09fAoMLKACDT6D0CXQEFICOnr4EBhdQAAafQOkT6AgoAB09fQkMLqAADD6B0ifQEVAAOnr6EhhcQAEYfAKlT6AjoAB09PQlMLjAscHzlz6B0QU+m3EAFx0BzKjvqQnMLHBeAZh5Bjw9gRkFFIAZ8T01gbkFzt1UGXTPQbINjcCuCnTXz5xupxSAOfk99zYIjFoALhT+na4BbMMuaAwErl3gz9XlE0cA1w6nB4FVgRGPAD6sAdxX4SLg6ky6T2BHBJ6tcZ6fxpoK1olpO24J7KJAZ+3M0fefNUm3TBPlFGCScEvg+gSyiEdpb1WiD1S8OyXsIuAk4ZbAdgtk8Z+q+HzxT8PtHoZM23FLYBcFuuvnRvTPYf9d+01ON4H9tutxArsg0F0/R9n/g5qAX1Z8fs5/pQnpJnClbXqMwK4IdNfPUfR/v/B/V3H31Sbh2NV+wd8TILBogYuVXV7SS5yreL7i5YpPKg7VUi06VeiqVeZQWfglAuMJZN/vrJ2svVlbXgV4p5nBN5v9dScwqkB33++uvbZbCsDbza10EZpPrzuB2QTubz5zd+01n35vbxNHAD+oLG5tZ2IDBMYSyD7//WbKW3EE8LVC+FUTQncCowlkn8++32mzHwEk+UcrOhcy0vfTirzLSCOwCwLZ17PPd9dN1t7sLYcyecNAdzAByaeMnA4UgraVAtm3s49vYvFnzS1mrTxXyXQLwNT/9drWMxWpbl4iLARtaIHsw9mXn67Ivj3t593brLnZ2/R9fj+uTH4/ezYSILA7Ak/UUP8w93CnAnCiEnmz4va5E/L8BHZAIO/eu7fivbnHmpcB05LIry/d8wcBAkctkLU2++LPIKcjgNy/reKNin0/Nphf0ggQaAnk8/j3VeQi4Ozt5pUM/lP3L1R8d+UxdwkQ2KzAk7W5fD5/EW31CCAJpSD8o+KB/KARILBRgVdra9+u+O9Gt9rY2HoByKbuqThb4SW8aGgENiOQj+vmswPvbGZzm9nKdBFwdWtJ8PGKj1cfdJ8AgesWyFrKmlrU4s9orlQA8vgrFT/JHY0AgbZA1lLW1OLa6kXA9eReqwfyqkDe93xs/S/9TIDAVQXyL/+PKvLfcC2yXekawHqiD9YDeduiawLrMn4msL9Azvlz2L/If/mntA9TAPK7uTCYIuDVgWhoBA4WyNX+RZ7zr6e93zWA9d/LxYu8fPGziryRQSNA4HKBrI2skayVxV3wuzzd63sk7xh8qiJvGup+Ikp/htuwD2QtZE1kbQzVDnsKcKVBnagHT1c8VvFIxfEKjcCuCOS/2H6x4oWKfBX3It7bX3lcU+sUgNUnyhcbPFzxUMXJilwzmG7vqPsagVEF8q97Dufz9V3T7Zm6/1LFRxUaAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBDYeYH/Ac9jCSl5uMURAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
set bat_low_icon to "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"
set bat_half_icon to "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"
set bat_three_quarters_icon to "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"
set bat_full_icon to "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAAEACAQAAAD2e2DtAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QAAKqNIzIAAAAJcEhZcwAADdcAAA3XAUIom3gAAAAHdElNRQfiDAwACRja0GGPAAAGQklEQVR42u3dTWgUZxzH8W8SKV2jJyk1mx56EKGHQkFjEYRCxUvYaujNeim1tEcVb9LaHooXD+Kl0kN7sep1I8VLaUEQWnyBQg9i8VCK2c3FSzYvSqnpIaRpappnknkmz26e72dO4vg8+zz/384zMzvrgiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJKquvwD41DnKAYeoMU2d76pe8yXVoMUGLCW7xA3NVd7d6AHZwhMMcYmvqWcnULN9znXEep+h8kLN0mHdLvnU4y+DGFn+Aj2gnH7jb0tbmIwaqKPVKS0CdJiMbmzgVcIcxWrEbfT4A+2gylHqsWlGbMW7HbbL/P38+xk3L37WGuMmxuE0uX1eO8S1bUo9Sq9jCuzzk13gN/nsJ2MdNXkw9QgU94a14C8FSAOrc9eDfI9rsjXU6uHgOMOCpXw8ZohnronAxAMe98OspIxyP09DCEjDIQ3amHpPWZJJdzJRvZuEIcNry95ydnI7RTB+wg9/Zlno8WrNpXi3/MVE/cMTy96RtHInTULPQxxEP+JyGVwqVG6LBZzwoVJNmjA5rzAQ7esYFaqlnJis1LvAsWJeZGFVpFCj/aOr5yNJogQg0ynbSz4HgPhe5kXousnSDi8F9wtULuhxc+z34p1ILngtcLttFP/XAHlerfzBR/2OOa4E9QtUL6mc4sMe91LOQtbuBvw9Vr4CpwEHGC7+UhgLVmSrbQR/zwT2UUqg+IdO0aXOfcX7k6codrL4prXhPFk/xJS+vvQOlFffx8g6f8sLaOlBacQMwzzy3lh8HDEB3ix+Aef7g9cXmPQnsdtW8BR8xwiQ8/70A5eEVmgtPgBuAXL3JJxBzCdjNe+xhjzeOAtrc4x5X+a3g/tWdhc2yi3ack8A+TjJbyenKZt1mOVnwrVXlq7gU5wjQx3c+MbAON2gUeINVeR3W4aUY5wAnLP+6jHIi8SvYztvljwC7+cUnBtZpjjeC5wLV3on5qvwR4KjlX7caRxO/gtfKB2Bv4iH0ttSzN1R+CWh54VdCO/hMT7VLwHT5APhpQTll57fkv/dOYOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQOYMQObKB6Cdegg9rfzslfvZv+nyAbi3QVO1OaWevXb5ANxNPITelnr2IgTgGnOJB9G75riW+BXcLx+A3ziTeBC960zhXxCuyrg/HZvOpvnp2HkanHIhWJM5ThUqf7Wu8NSfj99om/Ln41Wd6n48/otiHSitqsr/My8CxFsCVI1q3oKPGGES/CwgT48YXSg/uAR0uyoO/jvX0oHSilv8Gb5YWPuLd6C04hV/ikvPX6RvST0+VWyaNm3uM86PPF1ph6lAbryxk9JQ8F1dUj+twB57Us9B1kKzH6peUD8TJV+CqrQ38Peh6gWFjwDvUUs9C9mqcTSwxwYcAXZzLvU8ZOscuwN7lD4CQCN4+fDMT/uTGOVZsDaN8t3UmCkQgQsuBBuqxoUC5Z+JU5VmodsID/ichheFlRuiwWc8KFSTZvnu+oAP+Dr1qLUux/mmbBN9wA5+Z1vqsWjNpnmVx2Ub6Qcecz71WLQO58uXf/Fxj0EeLv+IUF1vkl3MlG9mAIA/6fBO6hFpTU7zc4xmFh/4GuAnRlKPSYXdYT9/xWho6Ym/One9yOsRbfaWvwm8YOmZwBZjPEk9MhXwhLFY5V/+UOhtPkw9NhXwIbfjNTaw7E+/8pBRnxLqYk94nysxG3z+qf99ND0X6FJtxmK++2Hlr33UaXpF0IXuxFz7F630xZAW+/l46YsD6gKTfMz++OVfzSBn6UR+Kt1tPVuHswxWVebVv/m3gyMc5hBbNzJ5+scs33Od8Rj3/P9Pka9+1jjIAYapM0yd7alnZZPr0GKCFhPc4gf/2w1JkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJkiRJknrB358vUZ38X7Y0AAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOmNyZWF0ZQAyMDE4LTEyLTEyVDAwOjA5OjI0KzAxOjAwICzFmQAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTptb2RpZnkAMjAxOC0xMi0xMlQwMDowOToyNCswMTowMFFxfSUAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHd3dy5pbmtzY2FwZS5vcmeb7jwaAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
set bat_charging_icon to "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAAEACAYAAABccqhmAAAACXBIWXMAAA3XAAAN1wFCKJt4AAAGGmlUWHRYTUw6Y29tLmFkb2JlLnhtcAAAAAAAPD94cGFja2V0IGJlZ2luPSLvu78iIGlkPSJXNU0wTXBDZWhpSHpyZVN6TlRjemtjOWQiPz4gPHg6eG1wbWV0YSB4bWxuczp4PSJhZG9iZTpuczptZXRhLyIgeDp4bXB0az0iQWRvYmUgWE1QIENvcmUgNS42LWMxNDUgNzkuMTYzNDk5LCAyMDE4LzA4LzEzLTE2OjQwOjIyICAgICAgICAiPiA8cmRmOlJERiB4bWxuczpyZGY9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkvMDIvMjItcmRmLXN5bnRheC1ucyMiPiA8cmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIHJkZjphYm91dD0iIiB4bWxuczp0aWZmPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3RpZmYvMS4wLyIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bWxuczpkYz0iaHR0cDovL3B1cmwub3JnL2RjL2VsZW1lbnRzLzEuMS8iIHhtbG5zOnBob3Rvc2hvcD0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS9waG90b3Nob3AvMS4wLyIgeG1sbnM6eG1wTU09Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9tbS8iIHhtbG5zOnN0RXZ0PSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvc1R5cGUvUmVzb3VyY2VFdmVudCMiIHRpZmY6T3JpZW50YXRpb249IjEiIHhtcDpDcmVhdGVEYXRlPSIyMDE4LTEyLTEyVDAwOjMwOjU5KzAxOjAwIiB4bXA6TW9kaWZ5RGF0ZT0iMjAxOC0xMi0xMlQwMDozNjowNyswMTowMCIgeG1wOk1ldGFkYXRhRGF0ZT0iMjAxOC0xMi0xMlQwMDozNjowNyswMTowMCIgZGM6Zm9ybWF0PSJpbWFnZS9wbmciIHBob3Rvc2hvcDpDb2xvck1vZGU9IjMiIHBob3Rvc2hvcDpJQ0NQcm9maWxlPSJzUkdCIElFQzYxOTY2LTIuMSIgeG1wTU06SW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDoyMmUzY2RlNS0xNjNjLTRkMmQtYmNjZi04YmNhOTMxYzUwMWQiIHhtcE1NOkRvY3VtZW50SUQ9ImFkb2JlOmRvY2lkOnBob3Rvc2hvcDo0NGVmZWJjMi1iM2E5LTM2NDMtOGFmMi1kZTI5NTVlNWNjMzgiIHhtcE1NOk9yaWdpbmFsRG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDo4YTRiMzc2MS1hMjhlLTQzOGYtYjFiZi1iZDg5ZjE4M2JjZGIiPiA8eG1wTU06SGlzdG9yeT4gPHJkZjpTZXE+IDxyZGY6bGkgc3RFdnQ6YWN0aW9uPSJzYXZlZCIgc3RFdnQ6aW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDo4YTRiMzc2MS1hMjhlLTQzOGYtYjFiZi1iZDg5ZjE4M2JjZGIiIHN0RXZ0OndoZW49IjIwMTgtMTItMTJUMDA6MzY6MDcrMDE6MDAiIHN0RXZ0OnNvZnR3YXJlQWdlbnQ9IkFkb2JlIFBob3Rvc2hvcCBDQyAyMDE5IChNYWNpbnRvc2gpIiBzdEV2dDpjaGFuZ2VkPSIvIi8+IDxyZGY6bGkgc3RFdnQ6YWN0aW9uPSJzYXZlZCIgc3RFdnQ6aW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDoyMmUzY2RlNS0xNjNjLTRkMmQtYmNjZi04YmNhOTMxYzUwMWQiIHN0RXZ0OndoZW49IjIwMTgtMTItMTJUMDA6MzY6MDcrMDE6MDAiIHN0RXZ0OnNvZnR3YXJlQWdlbnQ9IkFkb2JlIFBob3Rvc2hvcCBDQyAyMDE5IChNYWNpbnRvc2gpIiBzdEV2dDpjaGFuZ2VkPSIvIi8+IDwvcmRmOlNlcT4gPC94bXBNTTpIaXN0b3J5PiA8L3JkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbj4gPC9yZGY6UkRGPiA8L3g6eG1wbWV0YT4gPD94cGFja2V0IGVuZD0iciI/PmmDgZ0AABSESURBVHic7d17kJ1lYcfx7zl7kt0km01YEhODGMItggWMgFwcixquIjfBDpS2YrUXe3Ha2nHaqp1p60z5B23/kFptx+lFabUUW1GRKZcACYpYQK4BAsQkQpLNdZNNstnd0z9++3ZPNns557z3fX6fmTMLuZzz5Jzz/t7n/lTq9TpmFqZq3gUws/w4AMwC5gAwC5gDwCxgDgCzgDkAzALmADALmAPALGAOALOAOQDMAuYAMAuYA8AsYA4As4A5AMwC5gAwC5gDwCxgDgCzgDkAzALmADALmAPALGAOALOAOQDMAuYAMAuYA8AsYA4As4A5AMwC5gAwC5gDwCxgDgCzgDkAzALmADALmAPALGAOALOAOQDMAuYAMAuYA8AsYA4As4A5AMwC5gAwC5gDwCxgDgCzgDkAzALmADALmAPALGAOALOAOQDMAuYAMAuYA8AsYA4As4A5AMwC5gAwC5gDwCxgDgCzgDkAzALmADALmAPALGAOALOAOQDMAuYAMAuYA8AsYA4As4A5AMwC5gAwC5gDwCxgDgCzgDkAzALmADALmAPALGAOALOAOQDMAlbLuwBFV6lU8i5Cu2rAsaOPTmAbsCXrQtTr9axf0lrgGsDMNRt4F3ABCoE6UNo0s3Q4AGaeCrr4zwJ+BbgU1QYO5VkoK6ZazCpuN7AQeAtwIbAKWAwsGv3ZHbN8oXov8HSbf3cWsBK4FrgMeALYDOxGtYDIp4A/a7eAzSpxEyoyAuwEtgN9wKvAD4GngF2jj8HcShdTu30A3cCpwMXAlcC5qJ3pGkUy4vTNzEefy3XAAqAf2AoMj/tz84DeGK8TkkXo+x4ZBt4AHgDuBR4CNuZQrtha/aJ1Ar8A/CZwIwoCX/TJi9NzdgzwbuBE4ACwATg8wZ8bifEaoesAjgNuRs2s9cBtwHeBn+dYrpa1EgCnArcAHwWWplIai2sp8EFUI+sAXgKeY+IAsPii9s1K4HZg7ejPe1GTq/CaDYArgL8AzsE9yUXVBVwN/Aa6O+1HF/9mYCjHcoWiBlwEnAF8C/grchh2bdV01fcuVMW5Hd1VfPEXUyfqgL0EOB3d/fcCm4AduLqfpV7URP47NBJTaFMFQC/qKf5b4IRMSmPtqAGnoV7/Mxt+/TCwBwWBAyBbFeAq4B/QMGxhTdYEmA/8PvCn6O5ixdWJJvxcBry14dcH0d1/N0ePAFg2zgFuRWH8QM5lmdBkNYAPAZ/GF3/R1VCVf/Xoz66G3xtEY9e7sy+WNVgFfAaNyhTO+ACooDHkW4G52RfHWnQK8Nto4tCscb93EI3/H8y4THa01cBfUsB5F+MD4CTg83iYr+gqaAbmJajn/00T/Jnd+O5fJNcDf5h3IcZrDIC5qMf/7JzKYs3rBT6Axvx7Jvj9qPrvu39xdAEfRouzCqMxAE4DPoKXCBddB2rvX4OGZsd/XiOo538bJZ6jPkOdCnwi70I0igKgB/gYHu4ruhqwBPX6r0LNgPHNuGG0eGUXngBUNBXUH3BtzuX4f9GX5yRUPbFimGzCVQ+alXklRw75NTqMVq1tZ+oA6Gi7dBbHMtTULsT7X0MFuRiN/SdlP1qIMoCqoZ5B2Lwqk7fdlwM3AOehNf8TOYxqADuZeg1AtLTVk4QmV0Ft9y60sjKpi/ZtaI7AjxJ6vrbVgDmoWpLEmH8/sAYthvgpmou+C72RDoHmVDi67V5FQ34fRhf/VEO0Q4zVAKYKgC+jmWres2tidTS0ehxa7HM+qrq/PYHnPgF9jrkHAKj6vwP9g+M8ngV+By8RTsMitHnHKygcpvoctgFfAN7JkRODLL4zgH9Ctau418vXKEgz4KNou6g4/5gNwPvxXT4Nc1ET7Qc091n8HPgs6iNwECevF82ViRsA69DIW66qaCgpzhdlF1owdD+uTiathu7k16CNWJoxhGp0u3D7Pg07ga+izT/iWE5BAmAp8QJgLXBHMsWxcWajNeZXMvFsv4kMoi9pf1qFMjYCXyLeTMseCjA1uIral+1W3ftR1XRHYiWySA9qVl0OrKD5CVp7UABYup4FHo7x96MNdXNtNkcTS9otxF7gBVzVTMMq4OM0v6lE1LbchYZgLV07gRdjPkc3OTebazRftZxIP+oAtOTMRp/J5Wh4ttmt1evAPjQK4ABI3z7if/dXouHAdm6gFfSZH0LzRg7RRtMvmgfQrkPojbDkvBl1+l1Ea5/NMLr7b8eHgGRld8y//yEU9O3Mk6mg4NiHmn196AyIR9AuxetpYi2IF/4UT3Soxxm0Nk48ggOgbGYz+YzOZi1Ak5VA28HfAryGNib9T9REn7SZ4QAojhoaGnoPGvpr9VSlYXRH8jLgcHWgQDgL3UiuBr4C/AeqJRzFAVAcPeiwlWuYeI3/dOqMVQVdA7AutGr0dLTHx+eZ4NASzxQrhipK7RtR1b+dUZkRxmoADgCLdKNt425Hw8lHcA0gfzXUdrsJOD7G80QbgezATQA7UgXVLPcAf4D6igDXAIpgGWqrXU28JdlRDaAPHwVmE7sJ+CQNHY8OgPxU0VTQ89BS0yXE+zyifQC8BsAmMwvt/HVZ9AsOgPzU0KYQ1wInJ/B8+1D13/sA2lSORzWBeeAAyNNCNAnkSuDYGM8TjfHuRH0AXpJt03k/uvHMcgDkYwnqlFlNMltNDaApwPvwkmyb3hLgfUCnAyB7VeBC1BZbmcDz1dH87z68BsCadzJwoYcBszUbTcy4FHgHyezDWGfsHICBBJ7PwnAicJFrANl6KzrR53ySnYOxD08Bttb0Aic4ALL1DnRu/OkktyFk1ATYhrZjN2vGXGCJmwDZ6ETHQl2K9vaLuwKs0QhjAeCl2eWyBW2d30FrI3IV1N+zgvb7kSrAIgdANpag3ZevYnT8NWH96Chw9wGUyz3A59BKzlaGbyto89dfA26L8fpdDoB0dQDHoHHXK0nn2HUvAiqvfuD1GH8/9t6P7gNI13y0vv8q4m29NpVoEdDelJ7f0tOBpue2K/YN3AGQrhWo1/89JHv2YqP9eATA2uQmQDqqaHrvOaOPXtI5BqrO2EGgngFoLXMNIB2zUbv/etT7n9YZcPvRIRWv4va/tcE1gHQchy7+i0j3gM4DqO1fReO6Q+Qb6nXUQ11Dbds68XfOtRQ5AJJVQact/xJwAemfztuJZhdeh7YUGya/E2frqOYzB9VMtqH1CXHP0LMUOQCSNR91+n2Esa2a0zQXeBsKnWF098+rBjCCAq8TNUu+R/yTcyxlDoDkdANnopV+y8lmXX4HCp2i7QHQgWa4PZt3QWxqDoDknILG+88mmVV+zSjahT+COiPXAg+hAyqswBwAyagC56JdVpbnW5Rc7UFV/zuATXh/gsJzAMQ3Bx3AcAUa8gvZG8B3gAfwxV8KngcQ30rgE8DFeRckZwfROXTP4Yu/NFwDaF90tPrFwHtp/Sy/mWQIWIcOo3wt36JYK1wDaF8P2tX3cto7y28m6Qf+G1X/Wzqf3vLlAGjfCuCDaK7/nJzLkqd+dC79Y0xyAq0VlwOgPcuAX0RDfgtyLkvenkc9/0edPGvF5wBoXQ24AbgFeHO+RcldHbX970QjAFYy7gRsTRdwGhrvPzPfouRuENiAAuC1fIti7XIAtOYs4JfRrr6h2wD8O/BU3gWx9jkAmlNBG3teiu7+i3MtTf4GgceBu/Ddv9TcB9CcbtThdy5a5Rfq+xbtOrQNTfh5BZ9GXGquAUxvGbr4b0Yn+uS13r4IKugI8ruBNfggktJzAExvFVrldzUa789r773odSvjfmbtReAbwJN4H8LScwBMbwWwEG29tRXd9fK4+Opo04/6aHkWow1BsjKCdh9+BF38nu8/AzgApncIfeG3jP73ALoIs+wHGBl9zcHR/z4DWE22AbAbeBBV/Q9n+LqWIgfA9B5j7Oy2YbTwJdr8Mit1xmoAg6gdHnVIZiXa3+9R3PE3YzgApvd03gUYZwQ4efRnFuqo1vM4mvQT+zgqKw4HwPSyutCaNRvNSchq27EDwMNotd+2jF7TMhLqeHZZ1dD6gxVktwLxDXSK7f349OEZxzWAcqmhvQe6SX8+QtTnsBFN+tme8utZDlwDKJcaGgLsIf0AGEFLfe9GW33ZDOQaQLnU0P4DC0g/AA4A96Idfn33n6EcAOUyC9UAFpJeANTROP/zaNLP6ym9jhWAmwDlEjUB5pNeeA+j04b/B3iZ4h0+YglyAJRL1AnYQ7qf3ZNo0s9GPN9/RnMToFw6SLcPoI5mGa4D/hfP95/xHADlEtUA0gqA19HW3g/jiz8IbgKUyyx08c8j+c9uBFX9vwmsx23/ILgGUC5dQC/pfG770ISf5/GMv2A4AMplPhoFSNpuNOS3BvUBWCDcBCiPCqr+d6Xw3BuBf0Ntfy/1DYhrAOUxDzgGrQZMyjCq+kdLfX20V2BcAyiHKqr+95BsaA+g4b51+FDPIDkAyqGKLv5jSDYA9qJz/R5E/QAWGDcByqEDBcBCNBSYhDra1/8+1AcwnNDzWvMGibe/4sG4BXAAlENUA1hAMgFwGI31fwcd8eWLPx8rgStQB2+rtfGDwLtivn7dAVAOUQD0kkwA7AG+jU719eEe+bkEHTZTofWJV8PE3xW63wFQDo1NgCQ+s22o8+81irfnYUg6yW5vx/GGgG3uBCyHJGsAG9FGH0/jiz9k+4CtDoByaBwGjBMAI2jG3zeATQmUy8prK/CcmwDlEAXAAtpvAgyhD/0B4McJlcvK62XgHgdAOURNgHkxnuN1tLX3c4mUyMqsjhZ9vegmQDlEqwDjTAN+AS31fSmRElmZPYNGgIZdAyiH+WgWYLtr9Pej+f73owNOLWzfA36E5wGUQgUN/7V7EtAutMx3DQnMHLPSexD4OqN7PboJUHzziDf+vwEt9f0J3uUndG8At9Nw4K1rAMUXLQNuZ8LIMPAiOuK8L8lCWekcAP4a+FbjLzoAiq2CzgHspfWNQIaBJ9C4/9aEy2Xl0gfcCvz9+N9wABRbFdUA2hkB2Inaet/GO/yG7AngCzS0+xs5AIqtgkYAemm+CVBHnX0/Qaf7+GivML0E/AD4Z6aY+OUAKL5u1AnYbA3gEFrquwYt+rEwHEAbum4Gfora+uuYZofnGvEWhFTxSEKaGmsAzfYBDKA7//fRjj+WnriHs2xGE7SqtD5CU0H9PHtQc68PVffXotOcm9rctYa+JO2OMc8BFuNOprRU0Hu8kOZqAHX0WTwCPItX+6WpAiyN+RzfBD5NjhuyVIl38fYAJydUFptY1Ak4XQ1gBG3xdTeqAg7hAEjTMcBJMZ9jLzkfvhoFQLuFWACcTXpn1YcuGgZcgD6rqT6nATTL607c9s/CIuCdMf7+EJqlmWtIV1Hbod1CdAIfQHubWfIq6E4zv+H/x4tCYQea7/803uYrbTVgNfECYB8F2Im5Svxtoc4E/oh4S1VtYnNQAExX/d+B2v1P4jH/LFwA/DHxRtH60NTcXFXRcVBDMZ6jBlwP/B7xO0XsSD2oCTDVF60CPAX8K1rrn2ubcoarAe8GPgWcGPO5XkZ9Nbl7E+o8qsd8DKCtpi4AlhF/x9LQ1VAV804mf89HUB/OZ3ANLC3RmYzHAR9nbHQl7vXyxSz/EZOpobbIQ8By4o3pzwFuQm2j+9Eb9Ryqnraz7fFMVUXt9Ok66jpRDWCqGYC70Syvp5h8nf9q9IWtAGfQ3GdcRbsGh6yO9l88HjgFuHD0kcTkuT7UX1MIFeBm9AWKm2p+NPe4uYnPZTFqWt3H5HecHwMfQ3enyQI273+rH0c/HgNWTPJ5ZSoaWlqLmgGWjWb6XKJlwJNN0hpGbchovn89maJZyoaAHwKv5l0QGKsObgG+hM+GL5I5aALQRH0pA4wt9tmMJ/yUyfNoU45CiALgMJpB9liOZbEjRQEwUQ3gFdTh+jC+85fJftSp+0LeBYk0dgj9DNUCduVUFjtSFxPPAaij6uOj+O5fNo8CX8m7EI0aA2AEVSn/K6ey2JHmcvRmoIPo4n8cBbaVx2bgaxRsf4bxQ0J9wJ+jOeWWr6gG0NgH0I8C+i40vGrlcBD4G9RsK5SJxoQ3oWmO6zMuix0pGgWImgB11Pb/LppHcDincllrhoEvo+Z14Uw2KeQJNN3xxQzLYkeaizoBO9CX6Geo068Qw0fWtK8Dt1HQMxkmC4ARdHrI76JthSxb0U5APaP/P4jmanwfb+9dFofQXf+zqP1fSFNNC62jTsFfRzvLWnbmoIs/6gA8gPb4exRv81UGW4HPAX9CwY9hb2Ze83rgk6jqeQOaG23pmg8ci9r//ajq/yhe5190B9D07K+i05jirLLNRLMLGzahvcvuA34LOB/NVbfk1VDbfzFq/z+Dvkxb8iyUTWkE3SjvAv6REk2rb2Vl0xDqgb4XuBH4VbQn2vFo1ZQlYyHwdvTe1lGH7ANo51crll1oB95H0PLeZ/ItTuvaWdp4GPgX4A60OcL7gPPQ6qalaPjK5w1Mbaodfo4FTkNr0DejL5XH/IvhILroo+2816JwLu1oWZwLdQgtSNkA3IPWSq9CVddFoz+74xZwhpqqI68bBekm9MV6gnjbRjfWHBbS/L4MnhIuI+g93I5GYF5Fq/meQu9Rqd+nSr3utSRTqVQy38fkLOA6NPS3Dm2ssj3rQiTF369icwBMI4cAeAvaZXkvOt+tnxwPjojL369icwBMI4cA6EHt/wEKsG98XP5+FZsDwCxgPtjTLGAOALOAOQDMAuYAMAuYA8AsYA4As4A5AMwC5gAwC5gDwCxgDgCzgDkAzALmADALmAPALGAOALOAOQDMAuYAMAuYA8AsYA4As4A5AMwC5gAwC5gDwCxgDgCzgDkAzALmADALmAPALGAOALOAOQDMAuYAMAuYA8AsYA4As4A5AMwC5gAwC5gDwCxgDgCzgDkAzALmADALmAPALGAOALOAOQDMAuYAMAuYA8AsYA4As4A5AMwC5gAwC5gDwCxgDgCzgDkAzALmADALmAPALGAOALOA/R+GatypVlYrzAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="

set chargeState to do shell script "pmset -g batt | awk '{printf \"%s %s\\n\", $4,$5;exit}'"
set percentLeft to do shell script "pmset -g batt | egrep -ow '([0-9]{1,3})[%]'" as text
set percentcheck to (item 1 of words of percentLeft as integer)


on new_icon(base64Code)
    set percentLeft to do shell script "pmset -g batt | egrep -ow '([0-9]{1,3})[%]'" as text
    tell application "BetterTouchTool"
        update_touch_bar_widget "482F2657-A978-4D25-B9D6-EABFAD7E3B0A" text percentLeft icon_data base64Code
    end tell
end new_icon


if (chargeState contains "AC") then
    my new_icon(bat_charging_icon)
else if percentcheck ≥ 85 then
        my new_icon(bat_full_icon)
    else if (percentcheck < 85) and (percentcheck ≥ 65) then
            my new_icon(bat_three_quarters_icon)
    else if (percentcheck < 65) and (percentcheck ≥ 31) then
            my new_icon(bat_three_quarters_icon)
    else if percentcheck < 31 then
            my new_icon(bat_low_icon)
    else if percentcheck ≤ 10 then
            my new_icon(bat_empty_icon) 
end if
```

Comment: A standard AppleScript app run on such tight intervals making multiple `do shell script` invoking multiple shell utilities is going to be a resource hog. Writing something in a language like C or Objective-C and avoiding AppleScript all together in this case would probably be better on resources.  What's wrong with just using the built-in battery indicator on the menu bar? System Preferences > Energy Saver > [√] Show battery status in menu bar

Comment: This widget is not for the menu bar, its for the touch bar, more specifically, it is a script that runs in a loop on an app which then shows the returned string on the touch bar (here, the icon and the percentage) hence why I am writing this script. Now, for objective C, I would use it but I don't know it at all, I just got started into scripting with applescript and I have now undertaken to learn Python 3.. But maybe after :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step should be to increase the intervals at which you run the script.  There is no need to have it run **every 3 seconds** (!).  Even once a minute would be sufficient but I, personally, would set it to something such as once every ten minutes, since the battery level doesn't tends to only change once within a ten minute window.  Even if it changed twice (e.g. dropping from 97% to 96% then to 95%), there would be no negative consequences from your script registering the level going from 97% straight down to 95% in a ten minute interval.

The next thing you can do is store those base 64 strings in properties rather than variables.  Properties are set once and stored between subsequent runs of a script.  If the values of the properties aren't altered, then the script doesn't need to read a new set of values each time it executes.  As they are set at compile time, the overhead is reduced at run time.

The next thing you can do is get rid of the `do shell script` commands.  They incur a lot of overhead.  Instead, you can use AppleScriptObjC calls to obtain the information you need.  There is still a slight overhead in implementing AppleScriptObjC compared to vanilla AppleScript, but it won't be as great as the cost of creating multiple shell processes:

```
property bat_empty_icon : "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"
property bat_low_icon : "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"
property bat_half_icon : "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"
property bat_three_quarters_icon : "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAAEACAQAAAD2e2DtAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QAAKqNIzIAAAAJcEhZcwAADdcAAA3XAUIom3gAAAAHdElNRQfiDAwAChdhQi/dAAAHC0lEQVR42u3dT4hdZx2H8WdmgvZ2koVkYeaOSBdDQTC6cCYSCAjWoIzTZlA3JhsxpV2pi6wETbMo3XQRimAR0U1tu1LuBK1iaTAQtCQpIiGEyAhFMnNnk83cmfyhbcbFMI5jpvecO+d973vee5/PWYU5vO95z++93/ece8/NBUmSJEmSJEmSJEmSJEmSJEmSJEmSJEmSJEmSJEmSJEmSJEmSJEmSJEmSJEmSJEmSVNVIiX0aPMUxJmkySZMDqQ95wHVYZolllrjMO9yL3V33CXCQEzzDcR5PfVaG1F3e5gIL3EnR+Thn6bDhlnzrcJbx/hZ/jOdoJx+42/bW5jnGYpR6tyWgSYuZ/s44lXCVeZZDN/roBDhCi4nUY9Wu2sxzJWyTo//371Ncsvy1NcElToVtcue6corfsC/1KNXFPr7FItfDNfi/S8ARLvFY6hGq0H2+Em4h2J4ATa4Z/ploMx3qcnDrGmDMS7+MTNAKdVO4NQFOe+OXlRlOh2locwkYZ5FDqceknqwwxXr1ZjYT4Izlz84hzoRoZgQ4yPvsTz0e9WyNJ6p/TDQKnLD8WdrPiTANtUp9HHGLc8x5pxDdBHO8wK1SNWmF6LDBemFHDzlPI/WZGSoNzvOwsC7rIaoyV6L8s6nPx1CaLTEF5qp2Msqxwn1e4a3U52IovcUrhfsUV6/Qa4Vrv+GfSqPwWuC1ql2M0izY4434DybqY9zjzYI9iqpXaJTJgj3eS30Whtq1gr8XVa+E1YKQ8cYvpYmC6qxW7WCEjcI9lFJRfYqs0abNTRa4yIPdO+i+Ka1wTxav8nM+3XsHSivs4+UdfsoneutAaYWdABtscHlnDjgB6i38BNjg3xzeat6LwLqL8xK8zQwr8Oj3AjQcPkNr8wlwJ8Cw+jI/gZBLwBQnmWZ6QN44+oh/cYMb/I6/Jz6SeFdhd5miHeYicIQflniqIM/tz3wt8QSIt71apoMy5f998jLF3f7IpwZyAqzyyRDXAD/gm8lOT398g6t8PvVBRHCAr1a/BpjiH0PxX8is8XX+mqDfuO/E/KJ6ApwcivLDft5MuBDE8rnqE2A69Rj65rP8MvUhBDdRfQlYHpAbv3K+w2/73GPcJWCt+gQYrk8LrvPFPo84cn18J7A3h/l26kMIywToVb8zwASomQHLABOgd/3NABOgdgYqA0yAvehnBpgANTRAGWAC7E3/MsAEqKWByQATYK/6lQEmQE0NSAaYAHvXnwwwAWprIDLABKiiHxlgAtTYAGSACVBN/AwwAWot+wwwAaqKnQEmQM1lngEmQHVxM8AEqL2sM8AECCFmBpgAGcg4A0yAMOJlgAmQhWwzwAQIJVYGmACZyDQDTIBw4mSACZCNLDPABAgpRgaYABnJMANMgLDCZ4AJkJXsMsAECC10BpgAmcksA0yA8MJmgAmQnawywASIIWQGmAAZyigDTIA4wmWACZClbDLABIglVAaYAJnKJANMgHjCZIAJkK0sMsAEiClEBpgAGcsgA/zBiLiu84WKLUT+wYjqCXAt6gHm7vD2zzTXUtsJENvx1AfQVYAJ8AZ3U4+i1o6lPoCublafAIv8OPUoau2fqQ+gq4UQdwE/4w+px1Fjf0l9AF10uBhiAmzwND9yIdjVOf6U+hC6eJ0H/nx8HB9yg/dY4ELllrL4+XjFE++3w18s14HSilX+d3kMQrwTqLjivARvM8MK+FnAcLrN7Gb5wSWg7mKE/6FeOlBaYYu/zouba3/5DpRWuOKv8uqjN+n7Uo9Pka3Rps1NFrjIg912WC2YN76xk9JE4au6olGWC/b4UupzMNSKzn5R9QqNslTxEBTTdMHfi6pXqDgBTtJIfRaGVoPvFuzRhwR4kpdSn4eh9RJPFuxROQFgrvD24SGzqc/EUJrlYWFt5qp302C9xBQ470LQVw3Olyj/epiqtEq9jXCLc8x5UxjdBHO8wK1SNWlV724E+D6/Sj1q7clpfl21iRHgIO+zP/VY1LM1nuBO1UZGgTu8nHos2oOXq5d/63GPcRZ3fkSo2lthivXqzYwB8AEdnk49IvXkDO+GaGbrga8x/sZM6jGptKsc5aMQDW0/8dfkmjd5mWgzXf1N4E3bzwQuM8/91CNTCfeZD1X+nQ+FXuHZ1GNTCc9yJVxjYzv+dZ1FZn1KqMbu8z1eD9ngo0/9H6HltUBNtZkP+eqH3b/20aTlHUENXQ259m/Z7Yshyxzl+e0vDqgGVnieo+HL3804Z+kEfirdbS9bh7OMxypz92/+HeQEz3Ccx/s58/Rfd3mbCyyEeM//45T56meDpzjGJE0maXIg9VkZcB2WWWKZJS7zDvdSH44kSZIkSZIkSZIkSZIkSZIkSZIkSZIkSZIkSZIkSZIkSZIkSZIkSZIkSZIkSZIkSSr2HyFBVQpKF0EBAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOmNyZWF0ZQAyMDE4LTEyLTEyVDAwOjEwOjIzKzAxOjAw2BAPHQAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTptb2RpZnkAMjAxOC0xMi0xMlQwMDoxMDoyMyswMTowMKlNt6EAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHd3dy5pbmtzY2FwZS5vcmeb7jwaAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
property bat_full_icon : "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"
property bat_charging_icon : "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"

global percentage

set [percentage, powersource] to [|current capacity|, ¬
    |power source state|] of battery's info()

if powersource contains "AC" then
    new_icon(bat_charging_icon)
else if percentage ≥ 85 then
    new_icon(bat_full_icon)
else if percentage ≥ 65 then
    new_icon(bat_three_quarters_icon)
else if percentage ≥ 31 then
    new_icon(bat_three_quarters_icon)
else if percentage ≥ 11 then
    new_icon(bat_low_icon)
else
    new_icon(bat_empty_icon)
end if


on new_icon(base64Code)
    global percentage

    tell application "BetterTouchTool"
        update_touch_bar_widget ¬
            "482F2657-A978-4D25-B9D6-EABFAD7E3B0A" text ¬
            "" & percentage & "%" icon_data base64Code
    end tell
end new_icon

script battery
    use framework "IOKit"

    on info()
        current application's IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo() as record
    end info
end script
```

Additionally, I tidied up the `if...then...else` block so it doesn't do more number comparisons than necessary.

Comment: Wow! very impressive! These changes have actually reduced the power usage by 2 points ! Thanks! 

On another note: the reason why I make it run every 3 secs is because the icon also changes when computer gets plugged in, and unless I have a way to make it listen a change of power state (kind of what I intended cause I kind of want it to be updated in real time..